# Why IDs start with com.?

Tags: java, android, cordova

Like this one:

```
<widget xmlns     = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
        xmlns:gap = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
        id        = "com.phonegap.helloworld"
        version   = "1.0.0">
```

I see it also in Java and Android.

What does com mean? What is `phonegap` here? The company or the web site of the company?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question is not related to programming issue.

Comment: It's just a naming convention. You can find more information here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/namingpkgs.html

Comment: @CapDroid, why it is not related to programming issue? It is related to programming issue.

Comment: @ilhan "What does com mean? What is phonegap here? The company or the web site of the company?" are not questions related to programming, IMHO

Comment: @ilhan are you facing any error if you wrote this com.phonegap.....etc?

Comment: @CapDroid, yes `sencha cordova init` gives me error. I'm trying to write the configuration file properly. Because it appeaser that it needs one.

Comment: @ilhan you have to mention your issue in your question.

Comment: @CapDroid, but I wonder why com? I know the solution of the error; it needs a configuration file. What should I ask? "It asks for configuration file. Should I write one?"

Comment: @ilhan it's not necessary. you can use any word.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no technical reason why IDs or package names must start with `com`. However, no two apps can have the same package name, so the convention is to name your app based on your website's url in reverse. That convention means that no two apps will conflict, at least as long as ownership of your domaian doesn't change. In this case, this is made by `phonegap.com`, so their package name is `com.phonegap.xxx`, where x is a name they pick.

Phonegap is a cross-platform app development tool, so that you can write one set of code for both Android and iOS.